# Vue JS npm install takes a long time to run

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs3

So when I do 'npm install' on a vue js project it takes almost 2 mins to download all dependencies stated. I'm new to vue and npm in general and I want to know if I can speed this up by removing dependencies that i'm not really using. the info in package.json is the following:

```
      "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  }, "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0"
  }
```

I know I can do trial and error to see what I need but wanted to ask the community to see if they know anything. Basically is babel/eslint necessary for me to compile this vue app?

Pardon my ignorance in this subject, I'm new to it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use `@vue/cli` (which you currently do), you need all those dependencies. This is why [vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) was created (by the creator of Vue). `vite` requires almost no dependencies and it's much, much faster than `@vue/cli`. However, there are tradeoffs. Working with environment variables is quite different and anything depending on a `node` environment needs workarounds (e.g: service workers).

Comment: The good part is that you only need to run `yarn install` (or `npm i`) once. But still, a vite-based project is not only faster to install, but also in development (when serving).

Answer (score 0):

do "npm install -g @vue/cli" it will install basic packages